# Empty session variable

Tags: php

I am encountering this session dump in my php page.

```
Array (
    [login_user] => admin
    [id] => Super User
    [roleID] => 1 
    [session_now] => Array ( 
        [id] => 
        [roleID] => 
    )
)
```

Master.php snippet:

```
<?php
session_start();
$rolesID = $_SESSION['roleID'];
?>
```

Master.php subpage gb.php

```
<?php
print_r($_SESSION);
  if ($rolesID != 50 OR $rolesID != 60 OR $rolesID != 1) {
    echo "Access denied.";
    exit();
  }
?>
```

I can successfully login into the master.php, but when I need to pass the `roleID` into the gb.php for extra verification purpose, it passes `NULL` value as I have shown above. Did I missed something?

Comment: If I use session `session_start();` on the subpage, it will throw _A session has already been started, ignoring in *file path* on line X_

Comment: So what does the `print_r($_SESSION)` prints in the subpage then?

Comment: the same session dump that I wrote above.

    Array (
    [login_user] => admin
    [id] => Super User
    [roleID] => 1 
    [session_now] => Array ( 
        [id] => 
        [roleID] => 
        )
    )



the variables in the session somehow gone after my successful login attempt

Comment: What makes you think that `$rolesID` is `null`?

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you are having? Is it that $rolesID is null in gb.php or is it that $_SESSION['session_now']['roleID'] is null?

Comment: I'm not really sure here what make `$rolesID` `null`, I'm pretty beginner at PHP.

Comment: That is not my question, do a `var_dump($rolesID)` in *gb.php* to verify that `$rolesID` is `null`. If you think that the variable is `null` because you get an `access denied` message, that is because your logic is off, not because `$rolesID` is `null`

Comment: @FabianGillenius One thing that I know is when I am accessing the `$rolesID` from MySQL, it return value `1` from my database, and still accessible on _master.php_. Only when I am trying to use `rolesID` for the _master.php_ subpage _gb.php_, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem is in your IF conditions.

```
if ($rolesID != 50 OR $rolesID != 60 OR $rolesID != 1)
```

$rolesID can only have one of these values, so the above condition will always return true. For example, if $rolesID is 50, then it can't be 60 or 1, so access will be denied.

A better structure would be to allow access if it contains one of the values, which is what I think you wanted to do:

```
if ($rolesID == 50 OR $rolesID == 60 OR $rolesID == 1) {
  echo "Access granted";
} else {
  echo "Access denied.";
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Or even shorter `if (in_array($rolesID, [ 1, 50 , 60]) { ... }`

Comment: This sir, solved my problem. I can't believe the operator(s) can cause such thing. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Nicholas always verify content of variables before assuming their value

Comment: @DarkBee That is shorter, but I would also argue that it is less readable for a beginner.

Comment: @DarkBee I shall do that in the future sir.

Comment: @Nicholas IF logic can be finicky and hard to get right. It's a source of a great many bugs even for much more experienced programmers. A good trick is to read it aloud to yourself, to make it a bit more obvious. In the case of your IF statement, I would use the expected value of $rolesID, for example: "If 1 is not equal to 50 then access will be denied".

Comment: I'd argue that `in_array` is easier to read.   Which reads 'is my value one of these'.  When you have logical conditions that extend beyond one logical operator, it requires some head scratching - and understanding operator precedence and associativity (from someone that studied mathematical logic).

Comment: @Progrock You make a good point. As someone with very little background in mathematical logic, I wasn't too worried about the complications you bring up, seeing as it's (currently) a simple OR statement. I guess the implicit creation of an array inside of the conditional statement made @DarkBee's suggestion look a little bit more complex to me. Perhaps if the array was created beforehand, it would look less messy, and also more maintainable (if new roles are created and need access, for example). Something like: `if (in_array($rolesID, $allowedRolesArray))`